# Can ubuntu run all types of files, .rar, .zip, etc

Tags: system, restore

I'm new to ubuntu, and I'm just now installing it, i've backed up some files and I'm going to completely system restore and I'm saving some files onto .rar's. from my website database.

I was wondering if I can use .rar on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Run like? you would like to unzip a file? If this is what you are looking for then yes, it can. In fact you don't have to install anything, if it is missing for example .rar package it will prompt you then if you want to install it and it will do the rest of the job automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu can use .rar as well. Archive Manager (application) opens it with no problem, as well as  ZIP and other arhive type documents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are at least two command line tools available that can handle .rar files, and if one of them is installed, many GUI tools can use them to handle .rar files.

I recommend to install unrar-nonfree (it's not free as free speech, but still free as free beer), since the free as free speech GNU unrar utility cannot handle all .rar formats (there are actually different versions....). A third alternative would be 7zip, yet I don't know if the version available in Ubuntu is compiled with .rar support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Obviously, you can open .rar or .zip file in ubuntu.
Ubuntu has a default application named 'Archive Manager'. It can't open .rar file. But If you try to open .rar file or .zip file with it it will ask you to download commands to do that.And If you have internet connection you can download those commands. And then Archive Manager will be able to open your .rar or .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

but you will need to install [`unrar`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/unrar) package.